# Adding attributes to empty shapefile from other shapefiles with different fields

Tags: qgis

I have an empty polygon shapefile with certain fields. What I want to achieve is to merge two other polygon shapefiles and then copying their attributes to the empty shapefile.

The challenge I guess is that the other two shapefiles have different field structure and naming from the empty shapefile, so this script or process need to change the names of the field accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried joining the two attribute tables of both shapefiles (Joining is possible via project properties --> joining. This could be possible if you edit the shapefile and manually create additional tables with the column titles that you need. this will be necessary to join the two.

Comment: That will work, however, I would prefer something done programmatically